# Reduce Declaration of Function with the same number of arguments sort and return sort

Tags: z3, smt

I have an smt program that requires the declaration of multiple functions with the same number of arguments (and sort) and the same return sort.
For example:

```
(declare-fun main0 (Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool) Bool)
(declare-fun main1 (Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool) Bool)
(declare-fun main2 (Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool) Bool)
(declare-fun main3 (Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool) Bool)
...
```

Is there any way to reduce the declaration so that I can have a sort for those functions' arguments (e.g. body)) and all thing I need to define are:

```
(declare-fun main0 (body) Bool)
(declare-fun main1 (body) Bool)
(declare-fun main2 (body) Bool)
(declare-fun main3 (body) Bool)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
(declare-sort MySort 7)
(define-sort Body (Bool) (MySort Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool Bool))

(declare-fun main0 (Body (Bool)) Bool)
(declare-fun main1 (Body (Bool)) Bool)
(declare-fun main2 (Body (Bool)) Bool)
(declare-fun main3 (Body (Bool)) Bool)
```

If all of your arguments are Bool, you can consider using bit vector:

```
(declare-fun main0 (_ BitVec 7) Bool)
(declare-fun main1 (_ BitVec 7) Bool)
(declare-fun main2 (_ BitVec 7) Bool)
(declare-fun main3 (_ BitVec 7) Bool)
```

Comment: Body does not have any free variables so the (Bool) in define-sort can be dropped and so can the (Body) in declaring mainX. Also Body is an uninterpreted sort not a tuple of Bool. The following is sat, but it would be unsat if these were 1-tuples.
(declare-sort MySort 1)
(define-sort Body () (MySort Bool))
(declare-fun x () Body)
(declare-fun y () Body)
(declare-fun z () Body)
(assert (distinct x y z))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the theory of datatypes to make 8-tuples.

```
(declare-datatypes () ((BodyTuple (mk8 (a1 Bool) (a2 Bool) (a3 Bool) (a4 Bool) (a5 Bool) (a6 Bool) (a7 Bool) (a8 Bool) ))))
(declare-fun main0 (BodyTuple) Bool)
```

This does require going through the constructor mk8 for application though.

```
(assert (main0 (mk8 true true true true true true true true)))
```

(But such is the pain of trying to put inject macros into a first order function declarations.)